# python script taking a long time to run

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing a script to go through the files and print out the zipfiles and their creation date. My program works on data with less 5 MB, but if I run it on data more than 15MB, it takes hours to produce the outputs.  Below is the sample oof my code. How can I optimize my code so that it can run faster?

```
import os, argparse
from datetime import datetime


#Returns a list of directories of all zip files.
def findZip_Dir_list(cwd):
    userList = []
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.zip'):
                fileDir = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                t = os.path.getmtime(fileDir)
                userList.append(os.path.join(fileDir, str(t)))
    return userList

cwd = os.getcwd()
testList = findZip_Dir_list(cwd)

print(tesList)
```

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [glob2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2)

```
import os, glob2

# Returns a list of directories of all zip files.
def findZip_Dir_list(cwd):
    userList = []
    all_zip_files = glob2.glob(os.path.join(cwd, '**/*.zip'))
    for file in all_zip_files:
        t = os.path.getmtime(file)
        userList.append(os.path.join(file, str(t)))
    return userList


cwd = os.getcwd()
testList = findZip_Dir_list(cwd)

print(testList)
```

Comment: Is glob2 in python 2.7? I tried to import it but it says that there is module named glob2. Also, does this reduce the amount of time it takes for it to run?

Comment: You'll have to install it, but yea this is 2.7. It seemed fine to me but I didn't check against your method